# Users cannot access website in wwwroot

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am running Win7, IIS7, and have put together a website for an intranet using Windows Authentication. When I type in my IP for my URL I am able to access the website but other users logged into the intranet are unable to see the site. IE simply gives them a 'Website cannot be displayed'.

Below is the website's webconfig where I'm impersonating and have Windows as the Authentication mode.

```
<configuration>        
<system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <identity impersonate="true" />
      <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>      
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

Are there any read permissions that I'm missing?

Below are the current users and groups that have access to the site:

```
IIS_WPG
Administrators
USERS(myusername\Users)
IIS_IUSRS(myusername\IIS_IUSRS)
```

Comment: Are the other users accessing it by IP as well?  Can they even ping/see this server at all?

Comment: Yes, other users are able to ping.

Answer (score 0):

The users group should be a domain level Users group.  It looks like you're currently only allowing local users

Ex:

```
USERS(mydomain\Users)
```

Comment: Strange, I tried adding domain level users but I can't find the option... I'm sure this is the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to add them through IIS, or through windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a username and password in the impersonate area? or maybe not because you have windows authentication...

```
<identity imersonate="true" username="someUser" password="somePassword" />
```